# About customizing "BIRT chart Rendering" while Generating reports

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, reporting, birt

I need to put Reports into a web application and have selected BIRT. I would like to add the following functionality:

- Put custom code into generated HTML code of BIRT chart.
- Scaling Images of generated charts of a design, to generate multiple reports of the same kind but differs in generated image size.
- Generating image stream of a BIRT chart report so that the stream can be written directly into response output stream.

Any help, clue, external resource or advice on the above points, will be highly appreciated!

**Edit:**

Or any clues on the points, like even possible or not is also appreciated.

Comment: So, what is the question?

Comment: Is'nt there anyone, to whom I can award my bounties! :(

Comment: Thanks for your question! However, this is not really the kind of question that Stack Overflow is here to answer. [Read this for more information](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) Once you have a specific question about a specific problem you are having with code you are writing, feel free to return.

Comment: @AndrewBarber, There is no resource exists on any of the above points, and these requirements are like pretty much general expectation for any report generation engine. Give me any clue or resource on any of the above point, I will be happy. And Yea ofcourse I read the informations about how to question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea about first question.

---

To re-size image:

Consider having a look at [HTMLServerImageHandler](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.birt.doc.isv/engine/api/org/eclipse/birt/report/engine/api/HTMLServerImageHandler.html)

```
HTMLRenderOption htmlOptions = new HTMLRenderOption(options);
htmlOptions.setImageHandler(new HTMLServerImageHandler()); // your implementation goes here
runAndRenderTask.setRenderOption(htmlOptions);
```

---

Documentation for [RenderOption](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.birt.doc.isv/engine/api/org/eclipse/birt/report/engine/api/RenderOption.html) says:

> Still Image Render option is waiting to be implemented. Additionally
>   this is a place to contribute. So you can give a thought on this.